# Sample WSDL File Download

Tags: soap, wsdl

May I know where to download sample WSDL file? From what i know, there is a UDDI publishes over the internet which searchable by any users.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

i can provide you upto 5 working wsdls built in .net and magento.
This is the site where you can analyze and test the wsdls.[wsdl-analyzer-Link](https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/)
here are the links where you can view or download the wsdls

[sample](http://www.holidaywebservice.com//HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl)

Comment: this is also a wsdl link  http://www.harveynichols.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Comment: Any other website provide download of WSDL?

Comment: http://tres-bien.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1   http://www.v76.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 http://makeyourodyssey.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

Comment: https://www.teatoxshop.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 https://www.paperchase.co.uk/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

Answer (score 0):

Most services publish the wsdl at the same location as the service by adding ?wsdl to the URL.  You can also get xsd with the ?xsd querying

Answer (score 0):

For an example, any random WSDL will not do. You would want to have one which uses the most important features, which works out of the box with most software stacks.

I've written [an example WDSL](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf/tree/master/src/test/resources/wsdl) as part of a test library which should fulfill most the above criteria:

- Standard compatibility form (can't remember the exact name) for cross-platform tooling support. Notably, one Element for each request/response type.
- Request headers
- SOAP Faults
- XSD in its own file

not covered is

- Response header (rare)
- MTOM

Comment: What kind of criteria you have in your WSDL example?